# adding a parameter to a url that has a mod_rewrite value

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a rewirte rule that rewrites my portfolio urls from 
`portfolio.php?cat=cat-name&project=project-slug`
to 
`/portfolio/cat/slug/`

That all works fine and dandy, I'm wondering if It's possible to add a parameter to the end of the rewritten slug. For example

`/portfolio/cat/slug&preview=true`

I'm trying to make it so I can preview hidden projects by appending the `preview=true` to the end. It works if I go to
`portfolio.php?cat=cat-name&project=project-name&preview=true`

I'm just hoping I don't have to create a rule that has `/true` I've tied various ways to get the value or preview but thought someone here may have a simple solution

**Edit Adding .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
#portfolio
RewriteRule ^portfolio/?$ portfolio.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ portfolio.php?cat=$1&project=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ portfolio.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-z0-9_-]+)/page=([0-9]+)/? portfolio.php?cat=$1&page=$2&
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `QSA` as an option to the back of the RewriteRule (in the `[]` brackets). E.g.

`RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-z0-9_-]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)/?$ portfolio.php?cat=$1&project=$2 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was probally something simple but mod_rewrite is voodo to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite for such an example.
You may also include a hidden field with that appropriate value.